# Problem with fseek

Tags: c++, c, file, fseek

Here is my code.

```
if(fseek(file,position,SEEK_SET)!=0)
{
  throw std::runtime_error("can't seek to specified position");
}
```

I used to assume that even if `position` is greater than num of characters in file this code would work correct (i.e. throw error), but it wouldn't. So I want to know how can I handle seeking failure when trying to seek out of file range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always check for file length before doing the `fseek`.

```
void safe_seek(FILE* f, off_t offset) {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    off_t file_length = ftell(f);
    if (file_length < offset) {
        // throw!
    }
    fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);
}
```

Be aware though that this is not thread safe.

Comment: Or instead of using fseek use fstat.  This eliminates the need to restore current seek position.

Comment: Yes, but fstat is not guaranteed to be available on non-Unix systems, I think.

Comment: `fstat` should be available on any POSIX compliant system: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html

Comment: From [the doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/): `Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability)`. Only `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_SET` are guaranteed to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man`: http://linuxmanpages.com/man3/fseek.3.php, `fseek` returns non-zero value in case of an error, and the only errors that may appear are:

> EBADF  The stream specified is not a seekable stream.
>   EINVAL The whence argument to fseek() was not SEEK_SET, SEEK_END, or SEEK_CUR.

Falling beyond the end-of-file is probably considered not an error for `lseek`. However, calling `feof` immediately after may indicate the out-of-file condition.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, eof status is only guaranteed to be triggered on read or write.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( fseek(file,position,SEEK_SET)!=0 || ftell(file) != position )
{
  throw std::runtime_error("can't seek to specified position");
}
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. ftell() can return position outside file length.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error to seek past the end of the file. If you write to that offset, the file will be extended with null bytes.